# Disk is at 100%, Hyper-V vm will not start

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2016, lenovo

Due to wrong communication, people uploaded a ton of file in our file server ( a hyper-v VM) and now the VM does not have enough space to power on.

I did not built it but I have to figure a way to "revive" it, so here is what I know:
a) it is raid 10, meaning that I cannot expand the total amount of storage
b) removing the files will not free up space on the server group.
[server structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5k1Q.jpg)

although H/I/J are part of the sr650-group2, once I move files to another location, I see space free up on the H/I/J drives but not on D: which is the server group.
D: is the drive that the file server see's as full *

Is there a way to refresh the D: server group and/or the VM so it can boot again?

there are 9.5tb of data, that I have been slowly copying to another location.

I want to avoid rebuilding the VM.
Server is a sr650

Comment: Is the disk space inside the VM full or the disk space of the host? And do you really have a RAID built INSIDE the VM?

Comment: ": a) it is raid 10, meaning that I cannot expand the total amount of storage" - wtf? You could do that on any raid worth mentioning in the last decade or two.

Comment: I did not built it like this, if found it like this.

@GeraldSchneider the disk inside the vm is full

Comment: Then I don't get what keeps you from resizing the virtual disk.

Comment: the disk (d:) is initially configured but the lenovo xclarity as Raid 10, then whoever set the vm, added d: as the main disk, ( there are multiple server storage groups on this server). so now I cannot expand it since it is raid 10, does this make sense?